# Copying permission levels in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: permissions, powershell

As a SharePoint support team, most of our efforts goes in giving/revoking/listing the permission.

We would like to reduce the manual effort, I know Axceler is one of tool which greatly helps in setting up the permissions however we may not be able to buy it right now.

Kindly let me know if there is a codeplex/other solution available to give/revoke/list the permission on the SharePoint site/web/library/folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI will tell you that information by selecting Manage Permissions -> Check Permissions on anything, down to the file level.

There is another product from Lightning Tools called Deliverpoint that is much cheaper than Axceler's Contolpoint, http://lightningtools.com/products/deliverpoint-2010/.

Comment: any clues on the Deliverpoint licensing part?

Comment: If i's like their other products, I believe it a per web front end license, more WFEs, the price goes up.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a stab at SharePoint Permissions Manager from codeplex. I haven't used it myself, but it promises the ability to copy permissions.

http://permissionsmanager.codeplex.com/